# In SQL Server 2005 how would I determine the minimal permissions a user requires?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm the accidental DBA of my group and I've inherited a database that follows a number of bad practices.  ***Currently every login is a member of the sysadmin group***.

What is the easiest way to determine the minimal amount of privileges needed for each account?  I know I can use SQL Server Profiler to log all the SQL commands executed but it will return a bunch of information.  I can not think of an easy way to summarize all that data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to cut the noise out of a Profiler trace, [ClearTrace](http://www.scalesql.com/cleartrace/) is invaluable. ClearTrace “normalizes” queries, removing parameters such that:

```
SELECT x FROM y WHERE z = 1
SELECT x FROM y WHERE z = 2
```

are both reported as

```
SELECT x FROM y WHERE z = #
```

If you capture sufficient activity from the database and order the ClearTrace report by execution count, you’ll have a better idea of the common/typical query patterns and from this the permissions required. You can then investigate the non-typical activity and establish if these require a different set of permissions and/or are generated by a subset of the user base.

Comment: I love it! I've never heard of this tool before but it looks like it will greatly reduce the amount of profiler records I would have to sift through. I'll have to start tracing some data tomorrow and try it out.

Comment: Finally got the trace completed.  This program was helpful in the analysis.  Thanks again.

Comment: Great to hear it was useful.

Answer (score 2):

Find out what the logins/users need to do then match that up to server and database roles.  Here is a list of [Server Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).  Familiarize yourself with those server roles and see the least amount of privileges that the logins need.  Do the same with [Database Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The hard part is initially figuring out what the logins/users need to do before I can map them to any role. I wouldn't trust any person to be able to accurately tell me what permissions each user needs.